# Safari 11 Mac disable autofill

Tags: html, css, safari

I made some research but can't find how to remove the autofill on input fields in Safari 11.0.2 (tested on Mac).

I have a large form with placeholders that looks like "Car name" or "Pet name", etc... Safari see the word `name` in the `placeholder` and launch an autocomplete/autofill that overlap my custom html autocomplete from an API.

I understand it can be a feature in some case but on other it break the UI. Is there a valid solution to stop this ? All this solutions doesn't work :

- autocomplete="off" on form
- autocomplete="off" on input
- autocomplete="false" on input
- hidding with css like here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers

Thanks

Comment: Alas, Chrome has the same problem. Users and web developers are screwed.

Comment: found any fix, sir?

Comment: Sadly not for the moment....